# Strange Queue to Array error (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, queue

So my queue contains 5 Objects ( I have checked), but when I go to transfer those objects into an array, the last 2 always get left out, which is weird because I checked the size of the queue after the method is done and it says the queue is now empty, yet my array is always short 2 objects...

Here is my code for the into array method:

```
public void intoArray()
{

    while(!carQueue.isEmpty())
    {
        for(int m=0; m<=carQueue.size(); m++)
        {side[m] = carQueue.poll();}
    }

}
```

Comment: Check your loop condition. Do the elements involved change on each iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `carQueue.size()` in your `for` loop, the `poll` method remove the object from the queue.

First iteration of the `while` loop :

```
For : 
    1e Iteration : carQueue.size() = 5, m = 0
    2e Iteration : carQueue.size() = 4, m = 1
    3e Iteration : carQueue.size() = 3, m = 2
    4e Iteration : carQueue.size() = 2, m = 3   <---- Exit the loop
```

Seconde iteration of the `while` loop :

```
For :
    1e Iteration : carQueue.size() = 2, m = 0
    2e Iteration : carQueue.size() = 1, m = 1   <---- Exit the loop
```

At the end, your queue is empty because the of the `while` loop, the first and the second object of your array are replace by the two last elements of the queue.

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#poll%28%29) :

> Poll : Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or returns null
>   if this queue is empty.

Keep the initial size in a `int` variable  :

```
public void intoArray()
{
    while(!carQueue.isEmpty())
    {
        int size = carQueue.size();
        for(int m = 0; m <= size ; m++)
        {side[m] = carQueue.poll();}
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks boss, this works! I still dont understand why it wasn't working originally though.

Comment: You nailed the issue alright, but the `while` loop in your final solution is totally redundant...

Comment: Cmon, I mean I know that the while loop is redundant and that this code sucks... It was just a quick fix to make him understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You said you know the queue contains 5 objects, and why don't you try:

```
   public void intoArray()
    {    
            for(int m=0; m < 5; m++)
            {side[m] = carQueue.poll();}
    }
```

Comment: because the objects in the queue are a variable, not always 5 of them, but thanks for the help anyway brother.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with this code:

```
while(!carQueue.isEmpty())
```

second time this condition is checked is only after the for-loop ended.

```
    for(int m=0; m<=carQueue.size(); m++)
```

you run until `m == carQueue.size()` which is one index too far

```
side[m] = carQueue.poll();
```

when you `poll()` you change the queue-size which makes the "for-loop" end sooner than you planned and then the "while" makes it start all over again and run over previous elements.

Another way to do it is by using `Iterator`:

```
Car[] side = new Car[carQueue.size()];
Iterator<Car> iter = carQueue.iterator();
int i = 0;
while(iter.hasNext()){
    side[i++] = iter.next(); // here you can also use iter.remove() 
                             // if you want to empty the queue
}
```

Or, can also modify your solution as follows:

```
public void intoArray()
{
    int m=0;
    while(!carQueue.isEmpty())
    {
        side[m++] = carQueue.poll();
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like a good solution but I just found a simpler one, thanks anyways man!

Comment: @user2855405 I find it difficult to think of a simpler solution than this - but what works best for you :)